# php code server status?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have problem with this code
I want the output file to get the server status, but a part of the code is not complete

**i upload file here but not work and no show status of server :/**

http://nk24.ir/status.php

Next question: I do not have access to the source files
`vpnm.me/includes/get-status.php` Can I get file information in my host...

`status.html` connect to `status.php` Available at my host and `status.php` connect to `vpnm.me/includes/get-status.php` :)

If the source is to Receipt server status secret And information can be Receipt on my server.

I am grateful for your help

my code :

```
<div id="servers" class="modal" >
<h3>Status servers</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">Server Location</td>
            <td>VPN Server</td>
            <td>HTTPS Server</td>
            <td>Status servers</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col1"><img src="images/flags/us.png" class="flag" alt="USA" />USA CA : </td>
            <td class="col2">8</td>
            <td class="col2">8</td>
            <td id="server_us"></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col1"><img src="images/flags/us.png" class="flag" alt="USA" />USA DC : </td>
            <td class="col2">4</td>
            <td class="col2">4</td>
            <td id="server_us3"></td> 
        </tr>

    </table>
```

```
$.get('http://vpnm.me/includes/get-status.php', function(res){

for (server in res) {
    var status;
    var color;
    if (res[server]== 'down') { status= "Offline"; color="#FF0000"; }
    else if (res[server]== 'problem') { status= "Problem"; color="#FEF103"; }
    else { status= "Online"; color="#00CC00"; }

    $("#server_"+server).html(status).css('color', color);
}

}, "json");
```

Comment: You've tagged the question with PHP but there's none here. We need to see a sample of the output from the AJAX call.

Comment: your script returns plain text, not json mime type. add this to PHP: `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: upload file here you can see source of page but not work and no show server online or offline :/ 
http://nk24.ir/status.php

Comment: double check servers `IDs` in your HTML page !!